# Rounding numbers to the nearest 10 in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, window-functions, integer-division

I'm trying to solve this particular problem from PGExercises.com:

https://www.pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/rankmembers.html

The gist of the question is that I'm given a table of club members and *half hour* time slots that they have booked (getting the list is a simple INNER JOIN of two tables).

I'm supposed to produce a descending ranking of members by *total hours* booked, rounded off to the *nearest 10*. I also need to produce a column with the rank, using the `RANK()` window function, and sort the result by the rank. (The result produces 30 records.)

The author's very elegant solution is this:

```
select firstname, surname, hours, rank() over (order by hours) from
(select firstname, surname,
((sum(bks.slots)+5)/20)*10 as hours

from cd.bookings bks
inner join cd.members mems
    on bks.memid = mems.memid
group by mems.memid
) as subq
order by rank, surname, firstname;
```

Unfortunately, as a SQL newbie, my very unelegant solution is much more convoluted, using `CASE WHEN` and converting numbers to text in order to look at the last digit for deciding on whether to round *up* or *down*:

```
SELECT
firstname,
surname,
CASE 
  WHEN (SUBSTRING(ROUND(SUM(slots*0.5),0)::text from '.{1}$') IN ('5','6','7','8','9','0')) THEN CEIL(SUM(slots*0.5) /10) * 10 
  ELSE FLOOR(SUM(slots*0.5) /10) * 10 
END AS hours,
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CASE 
  WHEN (SUBSTRING(ROUND(SUM(slots*0.5),0)::text from '.{1}$') IN ('5','6','7','8','9','0')) THEN CEIL(SUM(slots*0.5) /10) * 10 
  ELSE FLOOR(SUM(slots*0.5) /10) * 10 
END DESC) as rank
FROM cd.bookings JOIN cd.members
ON cd.bookings.memid = cd.members.memid
GROUP BY firstname, surname
ORDER BY rank, surname, firstname;
```

Still, I manage to almost get it just right - out of the 30 records, I get one edge case, whose *firstname* is 'Ponder' and *lastname* is 'Stephens'. His rounded number of hours is `124.5`, but the solution insists that rounding it to the nearest 10 should produce a result of `120`, whilst my solution produces `130`.

(By the way, there are several other examples, such as `204.5` rounding up to `210` both in mine and the exercise author's solution.)

What's wrong with my rounding logic?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want to round to the nearest 10, then use the built-in `round()` function:

```
select round(<whatever>, -1)
```

The second argument can be negative, with -1 for tens, -2 for hundreds, and so on.

Answer (score 10):

To round to the *nearest* multiple of any number (range):

```
round(<value> / <range>) * <range>
```

“Nearest” means values exactly half way between range boundaries are rounded up.

This works for arbitrary ranges, you could round to the nearest `13` or `0.05` too if you wanted to:

```
round(64 / 10) * 10 —- 60
round(65 / 10) * 10 —- 70

round(19.49 / 13) * 13 -- 13
round(19.5 / 13) * 13 -- 26

round(.49 / .05) * .05 -- 0.5
round(.47 / .05) * .05 -- 0.45
```

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with an equivalent issue. I needed to round number to the nearest multiple of 50. Gordon's suggestion here does not work.

My first attempt was `SELECT round(120 / 50) * 50`, which gives `100`. However, `SELECT round(130 / 50) * 50` gave `100`. This is wrong; the nearest multiple is `150`.

The trick is to divide using a float, e.g. `SELECT round(130 / 50.0) * 50` is going to give `150`.

Turns out that doing `x/y`, where `x` and `y` are integers, is equivalent to `trunc(x/y)`. Where as float division correctly rounds to the nearest multiple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Bohemian's formula is correct.

The generalized formula is:

round((value + (range/2))/range) * range

so to convert to nearest 50, round((103 + 25)/50) * 50 --> will give 100

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of the Author's elegant solution that works:

I hope you find it useful

```
select firstname, surname, round(hrs, -1) as hours, rank() over(order by 
round(hrs, -1) desc) as rank
from (select firstname, surname, sum(bks.slots) * 0.5 as hrs
from cd.members mems
inner join cd.bookings bks
on mems.memid = bks.memid
group by mems.memid) as subq
order by rank, surname, firstname;
```